# Ubuntu as a Router

Tags: network-bridge

I am working on a project that uses a computer with a touch screen. This computer has 2 Ethernet ports.

Because of licensing problems, we need to use Ubuntu. The [HMI program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCADA#Human-machine_interface) we created with Java communicates with a PLC via using one of these Ethernet ports. But when we want to connect to our PLC, we need a router to handle all internet communication.
[Normaly what we have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elHHi.png)

My question is, can we neglect the router and use these 2 Ethernet ports to connect to plc from HMI and PC? I tried bridging but this solution doesn't seem to solve my problem.

PLC doesn't receive an IP from the DHCP server on Ubuntu it needs to be 10.0.0.9. Pc's and HMI's IP can be set automatically or manually. All I need is to connect to plc.

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDb46.png)

My network setting while using the switch:

```
  besca@BescaRoast:~$ ip a

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:30:18:0a:45:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.5/8 brd 10.255.255.255 scope global noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8f2b:7673:ee94:283e/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

3: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:30:18:0a:45:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

4: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:c5:f2:ba:21:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.22/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 85761sec preferred_lft 85761sec
    inet6 fe80::1d3:9f97:ba6c:23dd/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router

Answer (score 0):

Each host, computer, server can have the role of Router.
Linux is on most home routers.
To "transform" any Linux host into a router, just enable the IP forwarding flag on the kernel using the sysctl command.

`sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

`sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1`

After that you can set the default gateway in the two other PC and set the "Linux Router" like default gateway.